# /dev/ttyACM0 and lsusb

Tags: linux, permissions, usb, devices

Can someone explain me the connection between /dev/ttyACM0 and the output of  lsusb?

I am following [this instructions](https://www.zigbee2mqtt.io/guide/installation/02_docker.html#running-the-container).
It says "Update ttyACM0 to match your adapter location." I do not know what to do here.

```
lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 1058:25a3 Western Digital Technologies, Inc. Elements Desktop (WDBWLG)
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0451:16a8 Texas Instruments, Inc. CC2531 ZigBee
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
simon@simon-itx:~/Downloads/zigbee2mqtt$ usb-devices
```

Answer (score 0):

The output of `lsusb` says you have a Zigbee device attached:

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0451:16a8 Texas Instruments, Inc. CC2531 ZigBee
```

Now USB devices of a certain class have drivers which will create `/dev/ttyACM*` devices. These get assigned increasing numbers by the time when they are created, and those numbers have absolutely nothing to do with the output of `lsusb`.

From what I can see of the `lsusb` output, you probably only have a single of those. So if you do `ls /dev/ttyACM*`, you should see a single file `/dev/ttyACM0`.

If that is the case, start the container with this file:

```
docker run \
  --device=/dev/ttyACM0
  ...
```

and you are done.

If you see multiple files with different numbers, e.g. `/dev/ttyACM0` and `/dev/ttyACM1`, then the next step is to find out which is which. There are multiple ways to do this, for example you can look at the output of `dmesg` just after you plug the device in, or you can use the `/sys` filesystem, which has symbolic links that show the relationship.